# Adding cells to a UITableView, but they don't visually show, yet I can click and they work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Migrating an iOS6 app to iOS7 and this used to work before. On 6 everything works fine.

On iOS7 when adding cells to a UITableView they don't visually show, yet when I click where they should be they work as if they are there.

Its like the UIView isn't not redrawing itself or something. Very strange.

Anyone have any ideas where to even begin to look?

========== **UPDATE** =========================

Performing a recursiveDescription I get this.

```
   <UITableView: 0xf3cb000; frame = (0 0; 320 724); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1ac3ef60>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ac3e480>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
  | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0x1ac3f230; frame = (0 0; 320 724); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ac3f2a0>>
  |    | <TitDeleteGroupedTableViewCell: 0x1abddfb0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 208; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1abddd00>>
  |    | <TitGroupedTableViewCell: 0x1ac80210; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 120; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ac7ff50>>
  |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x1ac803a0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1ac800d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ac80570>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
  |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1ac80a70; frame = (0 0; 285 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1ac80bf0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ac80ae0>>
  |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1abc9b70; frame = (0 42; 320 2); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 107; layer = <CALayer: 0x1abc9c70>>
  |    |    |    | <UITextField: 0x1ac80de0; frame = (10 12; 275 23); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1abc65a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ac80f20>>
  |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x1abc90d0; frame = (0 0; 275 22); text = 'Create  plan...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1abc9170>>
  |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1cd992b0; frame = (276 12; 20 21); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cd99340>>
  |    | <TitGroupedTableViewCell: 0x1cf999b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 44; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cf99710>>
  |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x1cf99b40; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1cf99890>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cf99d10>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
  |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1cf9a1f0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1cf9a360>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cf9a260>>
  |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1cf9a3a0; frame = (10 12; 295 20); text = 'blah'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 105; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cf9a440>>
  |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1d297390; frame = (10 37; 295 0); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 106; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d297250>>
  |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x165836c0; frame = (0 42; 320 2); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 107; layer = <CALayer: 0x165837d0>>
  |    | <TitGroupedTableViewCell: 0x1d295080; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d24ee50>>
  |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x1d295210; frame = (0 0; 320 44); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1d1f3a60>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1c5c4e40>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
  |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x1d295480; frame = (0 0; 320 44); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1d28e4e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d28df50>>
  |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1d295560; frame = (10 12; 295 20); text = 'Budget-Blah'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 105; layer = <CALayer: 0x1d28e5f0>>
  |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1caaa710; frame = (10 37; 295 0); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 106; layer = <CALayer: 0xdbcc210>>
  |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd889590; frame = (0 42; 320 2); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 107; layer = <CALayer: 0xd827d80>>
  |    | <TitDeleteGroupedTableViewCell: 0x1abce730; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 164; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1abce6e0>>
  | <UIImageView: 0x1ac3ebb0; frame = (0 720; 320 3); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ac3ec90>>
  | <UIView: 0x1cda3300; frame = (0 88; 320 32); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cda3360>>
  |    | <UIImageView: 0x1cda27d0; frame = (0 0; 320 32); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cda2860>>
  |    | <UILabel: 0x1cda28f0; frame = (0 0; 320 32); text = 'MY PLANS'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cda2990>>
  |    | <UIButton: 0x1cda33b0; frame = (260 0; 60 32); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cda34a0>>
  |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x1cda3960; frame = (17 9; 26 14); text = 'EDIT'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1cda3a10>>
  | <UIImageView: 0x1ac3ed60; frame = (316 561; 3 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ac3ee40>>
```

So it looks like all the ones there are visible so this PO is correct. So I guess what is happening is when I click a tableviewcell that is empty (i.e. no data) but just has a background image with no seperators (i.e. it just looks flat and smooth). It still letting me pick it as if its a good cell.

So there are two issues.

1. The new data that is given to the dictionary feeding this tableview either doesn't have the data or it does and isn't redrawing.
2. Its allowing me to click empty cells, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: What happen when you scroll the tableview?

Comment: can u please check the color of the objects. Because the default color of the cell from ios7 is set to White if the object is in white color means it wont visible for u

Comment: Nothing when scrolling it.

Comment: The background is a custom image not white.

Comment: post your source code for table data source methods

Comment: @jgervin Can you please post your tableview code, and maybe some screenshots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal structure of a UITableView changed in iOS 7. This is not documented anywhere because there are no side effects if you just use the public API (add stuff to `contentView`, not directly to `cell`).

There is an issue if you do stuff like `self.superview` from inside the cell, since the view hierarchy is not defined by the public API.

Comment: This was the problem your solution fixed it. The cells were there, but you couldn't see them because subviews were not in the contentView.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a breakpoint somewhere like `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and typing `po [self.tableView recursiveDescription]` to see what your view hierarchy looks like. It would seem your cells are either empty or the layouts are such that the contents are off-screen. Then report back and please add more details to your question, such as code and screenshots (what it should look like vs what you're getting), etc.

Comment: I didn't get your update because you didn't reply to me. As noted in the comment thread, your `recursiveDescription` reveals that your cell's contents aren't contained in the content view.